# JavaFX CRUD app for rescue animals

Tags: java, beginner, mvc, javafx, crud

I'm fairly new to Java, and I've been working on the following program. It's a basic CRUD app utilizing JavaFX and MVC design pattern. I'm seeking advice because the class I took on Java only covered the fundamentals of syntax. So I need to improve when it comes to proper design and standards. Even though my program works, I don't know if I'm doing things the right way.

A couple of specific points of concern:

- I'm getting a recommendation from the IDE that I should generify `AddAnimalController`. However, I'm not exactly sure how this should be done in this context.
- I ran into a bit of a hurdle regarding serialization. I must use `SimpleStringProperty` for the data I want to display within the `TableView`, but `SimpleStringProperty` isn't serializable. So as a workaround, I created `String` fields to store a copy of such properties for serialization. It works, but I'm sure there's a more professional way of solving this problem.

Any advice on my code or things I should focus on to improve my skills is greatly appreciated.

Core classes:

**MainViewController**

```
package com.crud.gsjavafx.controllers;

import com.crud.gsjavafx.models.AnimalList;
import com.crud.gsjavafx.models.RescueAnimal;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

/** Controller for MainView. Handles ListView display as well as initiating actions on listView. */
public class MainViewController implements Initializable {
    @FXML private TableView<RescueAnimal> tableView;
    @FXML private TableColumn<RescueAnimal, String> colName;
    @FXML private TableColumn<RescueAnimal, String> colSpecies;
    @FXML private TableColumn<RescueAnimal, String> colLocation;

    /** Initialize ListView with the saved ArrayList, AnimalList.allAnimals. */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        try {
            AnimalList.initializeList();
            colName.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().animalNameProperty());
            colSpecies.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().animalSpeciesProperty());
            colLocation.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().locationProperty());
            colName.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
            colSpecies.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
            colLocation.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
            tableView.setItems(AnimalList.allAnimals);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Set double-click event.
        tableView.setOnMouseClicked(click -> {
            if (click.getClickCount() == 2) {
                editAnimalWindow(getSelection());
            }
        });
    }

    public RescueAnimal getSelection() {
        return tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    }

    /** Handles action for the 'Add' Button. */
    public void addNewButton() {
        editAnimalWindow(null);
    }

    /** Handles action for the 'Edit' Button. */
    public void editButton() {
        editAnimalWindow(getSelection());
    }

    /** Opens new window to edit selected animal. */
    public void editAnimalWindow(RescueAnimal selectedAnimal) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/crud/gsjavafx/addAnimalView.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            if (selectedAnimal != null) {
                AddAnimalController controller = loader.getController();
                controller.setSelectedAnimal(selectedAnimal);
                controller.setFields();
            }
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            if (selectedAnimal != null) {
                stage.setTitle("Updating: " + selectedAnimal.getName());
            } else {
                stage.setTitle("Add New Animal to Record:");
            }
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** Deletes selected animal after confirmation. */
    public void deleteSelection() {
        RescueAnimal selectedAnimal = getSelection();

        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Confirm deletion:");
        alert.setHeaderText("Warning: Clicking 'OK' will remove " + selectedAnimal.getName() + " from record.");
        alert.setContentText("Click 'OK' to continue or 'Cancel' to cancel this request.");
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

        if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
            AnimalList.allAnimals.remove(selectedAnimal);
            AnimalList.saveAnimalList();
        } else {
            alert.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**AddAnimalController**

```
package com.crud.gsjavafx.controllers;

import com.crud.gsjavafx.models.AnimalList;
import com.crud.gsjavafx.models.RescueAnimal;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Window;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

/** Create and add animal to AnimalList.allAnimals then serialize. */
public class AddAnimalController implements Initializable {
    @FXML private GridPane grid;
    @FXML Button saveButton;
    @FXML TextField animalName;
    @FXML TextField animalType;
    @FXML ChoiceBox<String> gender;
    @FXML Spinner<Integer> age;
    @FXML Spinner<Integer> weight;
    @FXML DatePicker acquisitionDate;
    @FXML TextField animalLocation;
    @FXML Spinner<Integer> trainingStatus;
    @FXML CheckBox reserved;
    private RescueAnimal selectedAnimal;
    private final ArrayList<InputValidationController<Node>> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

    /** Allows MainViewController to set the instance that's being edited. */
    public void setSelectedAnimal(RescueAnimal selectedAnimal) {
        this.selectedAnimal = selectedAnimal;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        for (Node node : grid.getChildren()) {
            if (node instanceof Spinner) {
                InputValidationController<Node> fieldController = new InputValidationController<>((Spinner<Integer>) node);
                nodes.add(fieldController);
            } else if (node instanceof TextField) {
                InputValidationController<Node> fieldController = new InputValidationController<>((TextField) node);
                nodes.add(fieldController);
            } else if (node instanceof DatePicker) {
                InputValidationController<Node> fieldController = new InputValidationController<>((DatePicker) node);
                nodes.add(fieldController);
            }
        }
    }

    /** Populates fields with the passed instance. */
    public void setFields() {
        final int maxAge = 100;
        final int maxWeight = 999;
        final int maxTrainingLevel = 5;
        animalName.setText(selectedAnimal.getName());
        animalType.setText(selectedAnimal.getAnimalType());
        gender.setValue(selectedAnimal.getGender());
        age.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(selectedAnimal.getAge(),
                maxAge));
        weight.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(selectedAnimal.getWeight(),
                maxWeight));
        acquisitionDate.setValue(LocalDate.parse(selectedAnimal.getAcquisitionDate()));
        animalLocation.setText(selectedAnimal.getLocation());
        trainingStatus.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(
                selectedAnimal.getTrainingStatus(), maxTrainingLevel));
        reserved.setSelected(selectedAnimal.getReserved());
    }

    /** Handles action for Save button */
    public void save() {
        for (InputValidationController<Node> node : nodes) {
            if (node.getError()) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setTitle("Error: Save Failed");
                alert.setHeaderText("Please review the form and try again.");
                alert.setContentText("Ensure all fields are set and contain valid data.");
                alert.show();
                return;
            }
        }
        saveAnimal();
    }

    public void saveAnimal() {
        if (selectedAnimal != null) {
            selectedAnimal.setName(animalName.getText());
            selectedAnimal.setAnimalType(animalType.getText());
            selectedAnimal.setGender(gender.getValue());
            selectedAnimal.setAge(Integer.parseInt(age.getValue().toString()));
            selectedAnimal.setWeight(Integer.parseInt(weight.getValue().toString()));
            selectedAnimal.setAcquisitionDate(acquisitionDate.getValue().toString());
            selectedAnimal.setLocation(animalLocation.getText());
            selectedAnimal.setTrainingStatus(Integer.parseInt(trainingStatus.getValue().toString()));
            selectedAnimal.setReserved(reserved.isSelected());
            selectedAnimal.setSerializableName(animalName.getText());
            selectedAnimal.setSerializableSpecies(animalType.getText());
            selectedAnimal.setSerializableLocation(animalLocation.getText());
        } else {
            RescueAnimal newAnimal = new RescueAnimal(animalName.getText(), animalType.getText(),
                    gender.getValue(), Integer.parseInt(age.getValue().toString()),
                    Integer.parseInt(weight.getValue().toString()), acquisitionDate.getValue().toString(),
                    animalLocation.getText(), Integer.parseInt(trainingStatus.getValue().toString()),
                    reserved.isSelected());

            AnimalList.setAllAnimals(newAnimal);
        }
        AnimalList.saveAnimalList();
        closeWindow();
    }

    public void closeWindow() {
        Window window = animalName.getScene().getWindow();
        window.hide();
    }
}
```

**InputValidationController**

```
package com.crud.gsjavafx.controllers;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class InputValidationController<T extends Node> {
    private boolean error;
    private final Tooltip toolTip = new Tooltip();

    /** TextField constructor. */
    public InputValidationController (TextField field) {
       validString(field);
       toolTip.setText("Input is required and may not contain digits.");
       field.setTooltip(toolTip);
   }

   /** DatePicker Constructor. */
    public InputValidationController (DatePicker date) {
        validDate(date);
        toolTip.setText("Cannot choose a future date.");
        date.setTooltip(toolTip);
    }

    /** Spinner Constructor. */
    public InputValidationController (Spinner<Integer> numField) {
        validNumber(numField);
        toolTip.setText("Input may not contain digits and must be within specified range.");
        numField.setTooltip(toolTip);
    }

    private void validString(TextField field) {
       if (field.getText() == null) {
           error = true;
       }

       field.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(c -> {
           if (c.isContentChange()) {
               if (c.getControlNewText().length() == 0) {
                   error = true;
                   raiseWarning(field);
                   return c;
               }
               if (c.getControlNewText().isEmpty()) {
                   return c;
               }
               if (c.getControlNewText().length() > 20) {
                   return null;
               }
               if (!c.getControlNewText().matches("^[A-Za-z]+$")) {
                   raiseWarning(field);
                   return null;
               } else {
                   suppressError();
                   return c;
               }
           }
           return c;
       }));
    }

    private void validDate (DatePicker date) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        date.setValue(today);
        date.setOnAction(e -> {
           if (today.isBefore(date.getValue())) {
               raiseWarning(date);
               date.setValue(today);
           } else {
               suppressError();
           }
       });
    }

    private void validNumber(Spinner<Integer> numField) {
        numField.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((observable, oldV, newV) -> {
            if (!newV.matches("\\d*") || newV.length() == 0) {
                raiseWarning(numField);
                numField.getEditor().setText("0");
            }
        });
    }

    private void raiseWarning(Node node) {
       double x = node.getScene().getWindow().getX() + node.getLayoutX();
       double y = node.getScene().getWindow().getY() + node.getLayoutY();
       toolTip.setAutoHide(true);
       toolTip.show(node, x, y);
    }

    private void suppressError() {
       error = false;
    }

    public boolean getError() {
        return this.error;
    }
}
```

**Serializer** (util)

```
package com.crud.gsjavafx.utils;

import com.crud.gsjavafx.models.AnimalList;
import com.crud.gsjavafx.models.RescueAnimal;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/** Serialize and deserialize ArrayList AnimalList.allAnimals (see: {@link AnimalList}). */
public final class Serializer {
    private static final String PATH = "data.bin";

    /** Serializer is static-only, and not to be instantiated. */
    private Serializer() {}

    public static void serialize(ObservableList<RescueAnimal> observableListAnimals) throws IOException {
        try(var serializer = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(PATH, false))) {
            ArrayList<RescueAnimal> convertedList = new ArrayList<>(observableListAnimals);
            serializer.writeObject(convertedList);
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<RescueAnimal> deserialize() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try(ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(PATH))) {
            ArrayList<RescueAnimal> deserializedArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (RescueAnimal animal : (ArrayList<RescueAnimal>) objectIn.readObject()) {
                RescueAnimal deserializedAnimal = new RescueAnimal(
                        animal.getSerializableName(), animal.getSerializableSpecies(), animal.getGender(),
                        animal.getAge(), animal.getWeight(), animal.getAcquisitionDate(),
                        animal.getSerializableLocation(), animal.getTrainingStatus(), animal.getReserved()
                );
                deserializedArrayList.add(deserializedAnimal);
            }
            return deserializedArrayList;
        }
    }
}
```

**AnimalList** (model helper so to speak)

```
package com.crud.gsjavafx.models;

import com.crud.gsjavafx.utils.Serializer;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * A global list of RescueAnimal objects; stores all animals in an ArrayList for serialization.
 */
public final class AnimalList {
    public static ObservableList<RescueAnimal> allAnimals = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    /** AnimalList is static-only, and not to be instantiated. */
    private AnimalList() {}

    /**
     * Populate public static field, allAnimals, on program start.
     *
     * @return the deserialized ArrayList composed of RescueAnimal(s).
     */
    public static void initializeList() {
        try {
            allAnimals.addAll(Serializer.deserialize());
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }

    /** Add new animal to the list, allAnimals. */
    public static void setAllAnimals(RescueAnimal animal) {
        allAnimals.add(animal);
    }

    /** Serialize the list, allAnimals. */
    public static void saveAnimalList() {
        try {
            Serializer.serialize(allAnimals);
        } catch(IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

**RescueAnimal** (main model - for brevity, I didn't include getters and setters, but if I should please let me know)

```
package com.crud.gsjavafx.models;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import java.io.Serial;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 */
public class RescueAnimal implements Serializable {
    @Serial private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    transient private SimpleStringProperty animalName;
    transient private SimpleStringProperty animalSpecies;
    transient private SimpleStringProperty location;
    private String serializableName;
    private String serializableSpecies;
    private String gender;
    private int age;
    private int weight;
    private String acquisitionDate;
    private String serializableLocation;
    private int trainingStatus;
    private boolean reserved;

    public RescueAnimal(String name, String species, String gender, int age, int weight,
                        String acquisitionDate, String location, int trainingStatus,
                        boolean reserved) {
        // SimpleStringProperty.
        this.animalName = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.animalSpecies = new SimpleStringProperty(species);
        this.location = new SimpleStringProperty(location);
        // String substitutes for SimpleStringProperty for serialization purposes.
        this.serializableName = getName();
        this.serializableSpecies = getAnimalType();
        this.serializableLocation = getLocation();
        // Standard String fields not used in TableView.
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.acquisitionDate = acquisitionDate;
        this.trainingStatus = trainingStatus;
        this.reserved = reserved;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I skimmed through your code and could not find anything from skimming.
Regarding serialization, if you must use `Serializable`, you should avoid using the `JavaFX` properties. If you don't have to use `Serializable`, keep the properties and use something like `JSON` instead. Have a look at @Jame_D's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455801/jackson-gson-serialize-and-deserialize-javafx-properties-to-json).